# Dynamic Select with form appearing at multiple location on webpage

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form partial that is displayed in multiple locations on webpage,  my header and my footer.  However I want to make a dynamic select and it needs an id to work correctly.  If I add an id to partial, it will appear in multiple locations.  How do I handle the jquery?

JQUERY:

```
jQuery ->
  category = $('#subject_category').html()
  $('#subject_product').change ->
    product = $('#subject_product :selected').text()
    escaped_product = product.replace(/([ #;&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g, '\\$1')
    options = $(category).filter("optgroup[label='#{escaped_product}']").html()
    if options
      $('#subject_category').html(options)
      $('#subject_category').parent().show()
    else
      $('#subject_category').empty()
      $('#subject_category').parent().hide()
```

_FORM_PARTIAL:

```
  <%= form_for( subject ,:html => { :class => "form-inline img-rounded subject"}) do |f| %> 
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.select( :product, Subject.products,{:placeholder => "Car"},{class: "form-control input-lg product_select"}) %>

            <%= %>

            <%= f.select( :category, grouped_options_for_select(Subject.grouped_options) ,{:placeholder => "Handles"},{class: "form-control input-lg category_select"}) %>
            <%= f.submit "Submit", {class: 'btn btn-danger btn-lg'} %>
          </div>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: How about using `class` instead of `id`?

Comment: Whatever the circumstances, an `id` must only appear once in an `HTML` document